# Disable SSL on an nginx server block listening on port 443

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to setup a server, which while listening on port 443 does NOT use it?

Something like that:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name  _;
  ssl off;
  return 444;
}
```

The problem with the code above is that nginx is forcing SSL on this block (ignoring `ssl off`) and fails on missing certificates.

*Some people may wonder why??, but please consider this an academic question of mine:)*

Comment: No, this is not possible. What are you _actually_ wanting to do?

Comment: I was wondering what would be the easiest way to setup a default catch all/default handler for non-existent `server_name`s. It looks like if you want to be "professional" and avoid untrusted cert warning on the browser you have to buy a certificate for the bare domain even if you don't have anything running on it.

Comment: Many certificate providers will give you both www and non-www for price of one. In that case, set up a vhost for the one you are using (assume non-www) such as domain.conf and then set up the other as the "default" by naming, for examiple, 0000-www-domain.conf. In the default, handle your "redirect" from www to non-www AND redirect everything else to the actual site. All-in-one, no certificate errors, and if you shop around no additional cost. For nginx, probably just order default ahead of actual site to make work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-2.3) states the separation of ports between HTTP/HTTPS comes from the fact the first data sent is different, since HTTPS starts the TLS session before sending HTTP over it.

There is no way for the server to understand you if you are not talking the right protocol.

Moreover, [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.2), updating the previous one, states:

> TCP port 443 is the default if the port subcomponent is empty or not given, and the user agent MUST ensure that its connection to the origin server is secured through the use of strong encryption, end-to-end, prior to sending the first HTTP request.

Having the content enciphered before transmission to the TCP 443 port is thus a requirement per RFC. You cannot beat it.

The reason for the requirement is an enforcement of the separation of OSI layers, TLS (SSL) being in the 5th one and HTTP in the 7th. There is no way they can understand each other. That is reflected in softwares, where processing of those parts are usually done by different code pieces (nginx handles HTTP, but defers TLS to an external library it has been linked with).